# angularjs input range write inside the crossing bubble

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

i want to write inside the bubble of the range , so i fix the design of the range slider and just i want to write inside the bubble number :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcgub.png)

so i want to write in circle the number so what i should used in angularJS or javascript code to write inside this circle , and too change the number with the circle which model should i used in JavaScript to be everything complete .

so i used this html:

```
 <input type="range" min="0" max="10000"  value="2500" />
```

and used this css :

```
  input[type=range] {
      -webkit-appearance: none; /* Hides the slider so that custom slider can be made */
      width: 100%; /* Specific width is required for Firefox. */
      background: transparent; /* Otherwise white in Chrome */
    }

    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
    }

    input[type=range]:focus {
      outline: none; /* Removes the blue border. You should probably do some kind of focus styling for accessibility reasons though. */
    }

    input[type=range]::-ms-track {
      width: 100%;
      cursor: pointer;

      /* Hides the slider so custom styles can be added */
      background: transparent; 
      border-color: transparent;
      color: transparent;
    }



    /* Special styling for WebKit/Blink */
    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      /* border: 1px solid #000000; */
      border-radius: 50% !important;
      height: 60px;
      width: 60px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      background: #ffa200;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-top: -28px; /* You need to specify a margin in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE it is automatic */
      /* box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d; Add cool effects to your sliders! */
    }

    /* All the same stuff for Firefox */
    input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
      height: 36px;
      width: 16px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      background: #ffa200;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* All the same stuff for IE */
    input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
      height: 36px;
      width: 16px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      background: #ffa200;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
      width: 100%;
      height: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
      /* box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d; */
      background: #000;
      border-radius: 1.3px;
      /* border: 0.2px solid #010101; */
    }

    input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
      background: #000;
    }

    input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
      width: 100%;
      height: 8.4px;
      cursor: pointer;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
      background: #000;
      border-radius: 1.3px;
      border: 0.2px solid #010101;
    }

    input[type=range]::-ms-track {
      width: 100%;
      height: 8.4px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: transparent;
      border-color: transparent;
      border-width: 16px 0;
      color: transparent;
    }
    input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
      background: #2a6495;
      border: 0.2px solid #010101;
      border-radius: 2.6px;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
    }
    input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
      background: #3071a9;
    }
    input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
      background: #3071a9;
      border: 0.2px solid #010101;
      border-radius: 2.6px;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
    }
    input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
      background: #367ebd;
    }


    input[type=range] {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      margin: 18px 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    input[type=range]:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
```

so hope that someone can help in this ...

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you must be having a tag to print value inside the circle. Now all you need is the live value being recorded. You can modify your `input` to be somewhat like:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="10000"  value="2500" ngModel="data" />
```

in the angularjs side, inside the controller, define `$scope.data` and inside the circle, just use `{data}` with your tag. This should do just fine

Comment: i want to write inside the circle

Comment: do you have the code for writing inside the circle? i mean apart from the actual data. do you have the necessary html tags?

Comment: if you want to write it with tag, you either use `<span>{data}</span>` inside the circle area. this will update values real time

Comment: but sorry this is range slider so i know that i can put span or i dont know but the difficult to me is write the number in the range in the circle

Comment: and i have a image in description

Comment: this is the best i can arrange: https://codepen.io/mountainash/pen/MeJaKx

you need to figure out the css for the value to be inside the bubble yourself